# no such method in flutter, the method add was called on null

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-dependencies

```
 FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('women')
          .snapshots()
          .map((snapshot) => snapshot.docs
              .map((document) => CategoryAvatar.fromJson({...document.data()}))
              .toList())
          .listen((avatar) {
        avatarsInfo.addAll(avatar);
```

when I started to debug, this exception occurred in the IDE  at the third line of the code shown above :

**Exception has occurred.
NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: The method 'add' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: add(Instance of 'MethodChannelQuerySnapshot'))**

also when I was debugging, the debugger always does pass the fifth and sixth lines for some weird reason, I mean those lines can't be executed by the program.

when I run the code, the text below is displayed on the debugging console

**D/HwCustConnectivityManagerImpl( 8132): isBlockNetworkRequestByNonAis, INVALID_SUBSCRIPTION_ID
D/ConnectivityManager( 8132): requestNetwork and the calling app is: com.sincerity.sandra
W/DynamiteModule( 8132): Local module descriptor class for providerinstaller not found.
I/DynamiteModule( 8132): Considering local module providerinstaller:0 and remote module providerinstaller:0
W/ProviderInstaller( 8132): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
D/HwCustConnectivityManagerImpl( 8132): isBlockNetworkRequestByNonAis, INVALID_SUBSCRIPTION_ID**

Answer (score 1):

the problem has been solved by adding the **await** keyword at the beginning of the query

```
     await _firebaseFirestore.collection('women').get().then(
        (QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
          querySnapshot.docs.forEach(
            (doc) {
              avatarsInfo.add(
                CategoryAvatar.fromJson(
                  {
                    ...doc.data(),
                  },
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        },
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this is it works but it only retrieves the data one cycle.

```
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('women').snapshots().map((snapshot) {
      snapshot.documents.forEach((snapshot) {
        print(snapshot.data);
        CategoryAvatar avatar = CategoryAvatar.fromJson(snapshot.data());
        avatarsInfo.addAll(avatar);
      });
    }).toList();
```

If your streaming the data try this

```
  Stream<List<CategoryAvatar>> avatarList() {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('women').
        .snapshots()
        .map((value) => value.documents
            .map((result) => CategoryAvatar.fromJson(result.data()))
            .toList());
  }
```

i hope i helped you

Comment: the IDE exception doesn't appear, it wasn't appearing always, but when I tried the suggested answer, the same peace of code is skipped, and the same text is displayed on the debug console.